# What is the runing time of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is the snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j  = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        //statements
    }
}
```

The outer loop runs *(n)* times
So the inner loop runs *(Sum from k = 1 to n of (n - i)) * (n)*

After algebraic manipulations, I get (n<sup>3</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>) / 2. So, the running time is O(n<sup>3</sup>).

Could someone correct me if I am wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to multiply

Comment: You got confused and multiplied by `n` one time too much. In the `i`th iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop runs for `n-i`. The total runtime is `(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+1` Which is equal to `n(n-1)/2` or `(n^2-n)/2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your n is equal to 5

Then the inner loop will run 5 times

first time for 4 times;

second time for 3 times;

third time for 2 times;

fourth time for 1 time;

fifth time for 0 times;

So total time will be 4+3+2+1+0. This is equal to sum first (n) natural numbers and it is given by ((n)*(n+1))/2. So by this, we can say that complexity is of order O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop ends up looking like this for a small example:

```
   1 2 3 4
     2 3 4
       3 4
         4
```

Clearly it's a triangle of some sort, the Big-O of which is n^2 since we don't care about the constant.

Even if you just started the inner loop at the same index as the outer loop, you'd have a square of `1 2 3 4` etc instead, but that would also be n^2

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop runs *n* times.

The number of running time of your inner loop, decreases per each iteration of outer loop. So the total number of times the *statements* (*body of your inner loop*) execute, is:

```
(n - 1) + (n - ­2) + ..... 2 + 1.
```

which is n * (n - ­1) / 2, which, in turn, is (n<sup>2</sup> - n) / 2.

Hence we can say that the running time of your algorithm is *O*(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when asked about time complexities, we tell the worst case time complexity.
In your case, worst, best and average case are the same.

Outer loop runs n times, correspondingly inner loop runs `(n - 1) + (n - ­2) + ..... + 1.` times for different value of i in outer loop, which is AP and sum is n(n-1)/2.

You might be multiplying running of inner loop with outside loop complexity, thatswhy you are getting time complexity as O(n^3).

Actual time complexity is  Θ(n^2) for your algorithm